# Align TextBlock in Button / StackPanel correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I try to align the `TextBlocks` to the left.
The button should take the rest of the area (Up to the picture).
How can I do this?

This is a UWP / C# App.

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        <Button Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

    </Grid>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Background="Transparent" Click="Button_Click">
            <Image x:Name="ImageFavorit" Source="/Assets/Stern/VGrau64.png"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should replace your `ColumnDefinitions` to this:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

And secondly remove `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` from your `Grid` then you can achieve to what you want:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    ...
```

Also it seems that you need to set `VerticalAlignment="Center"` of your `StackPanel` too:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

**Update:** Based on your comment that you want the text on the left side Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"` of the `Button`:

```
<Button Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
```

Comment: But the Text is still in the middle of the Button. I need the text on the left site :O But thx, for you answer.

Comment: @PaulePaul Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"` of the `Button` then it works as you want.

Comment: ahhh THX! This property I've been looking for!